# How to load a redis (lua) lib using 'docker exec' command?

Tags: docker, redis, lua

How to load a lib redis (lua) using 'docker exec' command? I'm trying to load a lib in redis using 'docker exec' but I get the following error:

> ERR Missing library metadata

Command used:

```
docker exec redis-db_1 redis-cli -a [password] FUNCTION LOAD "$(cat [path]\ZRANDSCORE.lua)"
```

Code [ZRANDSCORE.lua]

```
#!lua name=ZRANDSCORE

local function zrandscore(KEYS, ARGV)

    local set = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
    local langth = table.getn(set)
    local member = set[math.random(1, langth)]
    redis.call('ZINCRBY', KEYS[1], ARGV[3], member)
    return {member, langth-1}

end

redis.register_function('ZRANDSCORE', zrandscore)
```

On the first line, notice that the metadata is reported as [instructed in the documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/functions-intro/#loading-libraries-and-functions):

```
#!<engine name> name=<library name>
```

so much so that when I run this same code directly in redis I get success
[execution output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2rz.png)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (Redis 7.0.5):

call docker exec with "-i" option to bind terminal's stdin to docker exec and
redis-cli with "-x" option to read its last argument from stdin:

```
cat <script> | docker exec -i <container> redis-cli -x FUNCTION LOAD REPLACE
```

note: the script must begin with `#!lua name=<libname>`

In all other cases redis-cli gives: `"ERR Missing library metadata"`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

`docker exec redis-db_1 redis-cli -a [password] FUNCTION LOAD < [path]\ZRANDSCORE.lua`